# How to better change the position of fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Please check [this example](https://codepen.io/suedar/pen/QPbjqV). You can see it better at Codepen. I want the `#fixed` div to not cover the `#bottom` div. So I change the `top` property of `#fixed` whenever the `#fixed` is about to cover `#bottom`.

But if I scroll the page too fast, this situation still shows up. Do you have a way to fix it? Thanks for your answer.

[image]

```js
document.addEventListener('wheel', changeFixed, false);

function changeFixed() {
  const footToTop = document.getElementById('bottom').getBoundingClientRect().top;
  const viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const isButtom = footToTop + 0 < viewHeight;
  document.getElementById('fixed').style.bottom = isButtom ? 100 + 'px' : 30 + 'px';
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    height: 300vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
  
}
#fixed {
    transition: top 1s;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
#bottom {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="fixed"></div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use `"wheel"` event? Try `"scroll"` event

Comment: Hello @suedar, I'm having a hard time reproducing your issue on codepen, the fixed `div` never covers the bottom one for me, doesn't matter how fast I scroll. Sticky could be an option if you're okay with the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Comment: Hi @Jake. Please check the codepen example.

Comment: it's clear, you are applying a transition and if you are faster than the transition you will cover the element. It's not an issue but the intended result

Comment: @suedar I had to lower window height to reproduce the problem since it's based on VH, my bad. Why don't you simply modify this line to `const isButtom = footToTop - 0 < viewHeight;` to `const isButtom = footToTop - 100 < viewHeight;` for example ?

Comment: @Jake I don't think that changing the length of range is the way to solve this problem.It is that `dom` operation is display after `scroll`.

Comment: Well it works perfectly fine for me when I change your code to : `const isButtom = footToTop - 100 < viewHeight; document.getElementById('fixed').style.top = isButtom ? 50 + 'px' : 100 + 'px';` Same result without the issue.

Comment: @Jake But if I set the `top` property of `#fixed` 100px, the `#fixed` is a little above than `#botoom`. It did seems to solve this problem. But what if I just want the `top` property of `#fixed` to be `200px` which is the actual problem I met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this pure css solution using `position: sticky`

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    height: 300vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding-bottom:10px;
  
}
#fixed {
    
    position: sticky;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
#bottom {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="fixed"></div>
  
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about listen to the "scroll" event?

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', changeFixed, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to know is when you have scrolled to the bottom. Which means if you have scrolled to the bottom, you know there is a `bottom` div, and then you should move your `fixed` div 50px from the bottom. Something like this,

```
function changeFixed() {
  const documentHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  const viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
  // documentHeight - (scrollPosition + viewHeight) will be 0 when you have scrolled to bottom.
  if (documentHeight - (scrollPosition + viewHeight) <= 50) {
    document.getElementById('fixed').style.top = "auto";
    document.getElementById('fixed').style.bottom = "50px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('fixed').style.top = "200px";
    document.getElementById('fixed').style.bottom = "auto";
  }
}
```

PS: You'll need to add appropriate transitions if you want animation.